How can I store xpath value in a variable?
With XProc I try to get value returned by a XPath on a loaded document and store it in a variable to apply next.
input.xml
<root>
 <element id="test"/>
</root>

test.xpl
<p:load name="load-source-document" href="input.xml"/>
<p:variable select="/root/element/@id"/>

I tried this with Calabash but I get following error:

Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because "lexicalQName" is null


Please don't tag your title question. See [ask].

Yes, it is possible to store the xpath value into the variable. Try updating your code to:
test.xpl
<p:declare-step xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc">
  <p:variable name="id-value" select="doc('input.xml')/root/element/@id"/>
  <p:log message="Value is: {$id-value}"/>
</p:declare-step>

Getting the ID value can store into the variable like so.
